# accessing an array within an object javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, dynamic-arrays, for-in-loop

I have the following object:

```
myObject: {

 myArray1: [1,2,3],
 myArray2: [4,5,6],
 myArray3: [7,8,9]
}
```

This is an object that keeps growing in Arrays(dynamic array?). So I need to figure out a method to access it. I came across using a for( var key in myObject) with something like this:

```
    for (var key in myObject) {
     var obj = myObject[key];
       for (var prop in obj) {
           //thinking that this will print the first value of the array
       console.log(prop[0]);
     }
    }
```

but it doesn't work it prints undefined. I know using a for in is not the way to access an object correctly. I'm wondering if anyone could suggest a method to access the values of this object through a loop.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: Why do you think that `for...in` works differently for objects than it works for arrays?

Comment: @FelixKling This is very interesting. I thought for some reason it wasn't recommended. I don't remember where I read it.

Comment: Well, yeah, you shouldn't use `for..in` for arrays, but that doesn't mean that it works differently for arrays than it does for objects.

Comment: @FeliKling It makes sense now for me. Your link is very helpful in how to use for in when the data is unknown

Comment: @FeliKling I guess the question now is, if I want to access a certain part of that array when using obj[prop]. I will just do something like obj[1]. If I want to access the second element of the array for example?

Comment: `obj[1]` would access the second element of the array, if that's what you wanted to know. Or you could directly write `myObject[key][1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating an object with `for..in` is okay, but not an array. Because when you sue `for..in` with an array, it will not get the array values, but the array indices. So, you should be doing something like this

```
for (var key in myObject) {
    var currentArray = myObject[key];
    for(var i = 0; i < currentArray.length; i += 1) {
        console.log(currentArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works. And I guess this is the right way to do it??

Comment: @MauricioSanchez Indeed, this is how arrays have to iterated (or `Array.forEach`). *NEVER* use `for..in` with Arrays.

Comment: Although the method that vivek_nk suggested, it worked as well. I guess it is a matter of better coding practices??

Comment: @MauricioSanchez Well, if you really know what you are doing, that is fine. But don't use `for..in` with arrays.

Comment: @MauricioSanchez Also read this [section from the MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Description). It says why you should not use that method.

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake in 2nd loop. obj is the array and prop is the index

```
for (var key in myObject) {
  var obj = myObject[key];
   for (var prop in obj) {
       //this will print the first value of the array
   console.log(obj[prop]); //obj is the array and prop is the index
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`prop` is the index of the array, its not the array. `obj` is the array. So it should be:

```
console.log(obj[prop]);
```